# Como fazer app Ionic executando tarefa em segundo plano?

Tags: android, ionic, ios

Olá, estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo Ionic (Android e IOS) e esse aplicativo precisa executar uma tarefa em segundo plano a cada 1 minuto mesmo se o aplicativo tenha sido fechado ou o celular reiniciado. Eu encontrei alguns plugins para tarefas em segundo plano, mas quando fecho o aplicativo a tarefa é encerrada, e não encontrei nenhum que inicie a tarefa automaticamente quando o celular é iniciado.

Pesquisando sobre desenvolvimento nativo eu encontrei alguns recursos do Android que permitem fazer isso: WorkManager, Job Scheduler e Services. Mas não encontrei nenhum plugin Ionic que me possibilite utilizar esses recursos.

Existe alguma forma de fazer isso com Ionic?

Answer (score 0):

Tarefa em "segundo plano" é uma coisa, Job é outra, o Job pode ser temporizado como também pode ser em "tempo real". Note que no Android 10 ou superior (não me recordo bem) se fizer muito uso disso, ou um uso mau disso, o proprio sistema operacional percebe e pode reduzir a frequência, pq os Jobs são muitos custosos para o aparelho.

Lembre-se, Ionic é Cordova (ou Capacitor), sendo Cordova que usará no núcleo então tem alguns plugins por ai:

- https://github.com/raphaelmerx/cordova-plugin-scheduler (outras libs em https://github.com/search?q=cordova+Scheduler)

E apesar de escrito em JavaScript e não TypeScript, é perfeitamente funcional acessar propriedades no escopo de `Window`, como é o caso desse plugin citado:

`window.SchedulerPlugin.configure(...`

Podendo usar:

```
declare var window: any;
```